# How to measure performance of charting libraries in Browser

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, browser, rendering

I have been trying to look around different angular charting libraries that are available in the market. I have come across `ng2-charts`. I wanted to collect some stats similar to what the [uPlot](https://github.com/leeoniya/uPlot#performance) has provided here.

How can I generate similar stats for the different chart libraries that I want to compare ? From google, I found lighthouse but it measures page load time, I want to collect stats of just the charting components that I will be creating for spike.

I know its a vast area to answer but few links and steps would make a lot of differnce.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`ng2-charts` relies on Chart.js v2, which is listed as "Chart.js" in uPlot's benchmarks. i imagine there would be some additional overhead for the ng wrapper. most other charting libs that are not listed there rely one of these for the core rendering code.

the way i test them is to implement the benchmark and manually record several pageload performance profiles using Chrome's DevTools. it's a tedious, manual process which is not automated in any way.

i'm sure it's possible to use lighthouse for this, but figuring out exactly which traces to enable and measure would take more effort than spending an hour once every 2 months just running them manually.